# How to say "Cultural Identity"

Tags: culture

I want to say, "Okinawan people have a very strong cultural identity". Any idea on how to say this concept in Japanese?

Would it be 「沖縄の民族は文化のアイデンティティがつよいです。」？

Answer (score 6):

The literal translation is [文化的アイデンティティ](http://www.nihongokyoshi.co.jp/manbow/manbow.php?id=223&TAB=2), but it's only a sociological term in Japan. If you're trying to make yourself understood by those other than graduate students, it's better to say such as:

> 沖縄の人々は沖縄文化への帰属意識がとても強いです。
>
> 沖縄の人々は文化的な一体性がとても強いです。
>
> 沖縄の人々は沖縄人（であるという）意識がとても強いです。
>
> 沖縄の人々は自分たちの文化にとても誇りを持っています。

according to your context.

By the way, 民族 is anything but a vanilla word for "people" (it means "ethnic group"). There are many words in Japanese that can be translated into "people", but every word has distinct usage. If you just mean ordinary people, you should choose 人々 "persons" or 人たち "folks".